# Javascript Sort Array without changing index

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array with custom index (id) and name and only want to sort the names without changing the index (id). See below my array. Is this possible with javascript ?

```
var aanvragerslijst = [];

    if (item.get_item("Aanvrager")) {
        var aanvragerID = item.get_item("ID");
        var aanvrager = item.get_item("Aanvrager");
        aanvragerslijst[aanvragerID] = aanvrager;
    }
```

i use this array to fill a select item =>

```
$.each(aanvragerslijst, function (key, value) {
    if (value) {
        $('#LKAanvrager').append($("<option/>", {
            value: key,
            text: value
        }));
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you add your current 'array' and your expected output to your post. It looks like you're talking about objects rather than arrays.

Comment: Well it was a solution i found on the web. Because it's the only way i can add my items to the select option with id and value. do you know maybe an other solution ?

Comment: Maybe if you could add your current and expected output I would. As it stands your question is unclear (to me).

Answer (score 0):

Then you shouldn't use the `id` as a key. Put the `id` along with the `aanvrager` in an object, and set that as the value of the array:

```
aanvragerslijst[] = {
    id: item.get_item("ID"),
    aanvrager: item.get_item("Aanvrager")
}
```

Then you can sort the `aanvragerslijst` any way you want, without losing the `id`.

Comment: Well i'm using it to fill this select item =>

    $.each(aanvragerslijst, function (key, value) {
        if (value) {
            $('#LKAanvrager').append($("<option/>", {
                value: key,
                text: value
            }));
        }
    });

Comment: So you get to change that function to get the id from the object rather than using the key.

Comment: Well the id is important because it's a sharepoint listitem id. If i change this and add an item by using my form and the select option then it will be invalid when using the sort function.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of what you're trying to do is contradictory. You can't sort an array and expect its indexes to stay the same. *The indexes define the order of the array*.

The answer is to not use your IDs as the array indexes. Populate the array with objects:

```
var aanvragerslijst = [];

if (item.get_item("Aanvrager")) {
    aanvragerslijst.push({
        id: item.get_item("ID"),
        value: item.get_item("Aanvrager")
    });
}
```

Sort it:

```
aanvragerslijst.sort(function (l, r) { return l.value.localeCompare(r.value); });
```

And when you want to populate your dropdown, get the ID and values out of these objects instead of using the array indices:

```
$.each(aanvragerslijst, function (key, value) {
    if (value) {
        $('#LKAanvrager').append($("<option/>", {
            value: value.id,
            text: value.value
        }));
    }
});
```